# '/execute if entity' but with relative coordinates?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to use the below command:

`/execute if entity @p[x=-1856.5,y=122.0,z=-133.5,distance=..3.5] run tp @p ~-4 ~1 ~`

but using relative coordinates to the command block instead of these specific ones.
Is that possible?

Edit: Also, could I compress various relative coordinates into one single command block?
What I mean is, for example (I'm not sure if the syntax is correct):

`/execute if entity @p[x=~1,y=~1,z=~1] and [x=~2,y=~2,z=~2] run tp @p ~-4 ~1 ~`

Comment: What should your "and" do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is `/execute positioned`:

```
/execute positioned ~ ~ ~10 if entity @e[distance=..3] run <command>
```

This runs the command if there's an entity within a 3 block radius circle around a position 10 blocks into positive Z direction from you.